# Producing dataframe in R with rows summing to same number, including all possible combinations of numbers in each column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe in R.

I have 4 categories (e.g. Blue, Red, Yellow, Green) and I would like each row to sum to 100%. For each category I want to create incrimental differences of 5% units and produce a dataframe which has all possible combinations of numbers (to nearest 5%) for the 4 categories. I realise I am not explaining this well at all, so I have tried to show what I mean in the following table:

| Blue | Red | Yellow | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 95 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 95 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 5 | 95 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 95 | 5 | 0 |
| 0 | 95 | 0 | 5 |
| 5 | 0 | 95 | 0 |
| 0 | 5 | 95 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 95 | 5 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 95 |
| 0 | 5 | 0 | 95 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | 95 |
| 90 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 90 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 90 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 10 | 90 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 90 | 10 | 0 |
| 0 | 90 | 0 | 10 |
| 10 | 0 | 90 | 0 |
| 0 | 10 | 90 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 90 | 10 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 90 |
| 0 | 10 | 0 | 90 |
| 0 | 0 | 10 | 90 |
| 90 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 90 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 90 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 90 | 5 | 0 |
| 5 | 90 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 90 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 90 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 90 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 | 90 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 90 |
| 5 | 0 | 5 | 90 |
| 0 | 5 | 5 | 90 |
| 85 | 15 | 0 | 0 |
| 85 | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| 85 | 0 | 0 | 15 |
| 15 | 85 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 85 | 15 | 0 |
| 0 | 85 | 0 | 15 |
| 15 | 0 | 85 | 0 |
| 0 | 15 | 85 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 85 | 15 |
| 15 | 0 | 0 | 85 |
| 0 | 15 | 0 | 85 |
| 0 | 0 | 15 | 85 |
| 85 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 85 | 10 | 0 | 5 |
| 85 | 5 | 10 | 0 |
| 85 | 0 | 10 | 5 |
| 85 | 5 | 0 | 10 |
| 85 | 0 | 5 | 10 |
| 10 | 85 | 5 | 0 |
| 10 | 85 | 0 | 5 |
| 5 | 85 | 10 | 0 |
| 0 | 85 | 10 | 5 |
| 5 | 85 | 0 | 10 |
| 0 | 85 | 5 | 10 |
| 10 | 5 | 85 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 85 | 5 |
| 5 | 10 | 85 | 0 |
| 0 | 10 | 85 | 5 |
| 5 | 0 | 85 | 10 |
| 0 | 5 | 85 | 10 |
| 10 | 5 | 0 | 85 |
| 10 | 0 | 5 | 85 |
| 5 | 10 | 0 | 85 |
| 0 | 10 | 5 | 85 |
| 5 | 0 | 10 | 85 |
| 0 | 5 | 10 | 85 |
| 85 | 5 | 5 | 5 |

I am struggling to know where to start here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest three `for` loops and bind the results together:

```r
target_df <- data.frame()

for (i in seq(95, 0, by = -5)) {
  for (j in seq(100 - i, 0, by = -5)) {
    for(k in seq(100 - i - j, 0, by = -5)) {
      target_df <- rbind(target_df, data.frame(Blue = i, Red = j, Yellow = k, Green = 100 - i - j - k))
    }
  }
}
```

This returns

```r
    Blue Red Yellow Green
1     95   5      0     0
2     95   0      5     0
3     95   0      0     5
4     90  10      0     0
5     90   5      5     0
6     90   5      0     5
7     90   0     10     0
8     90   0      5     5
9     90   0      0    10
10    85  15      0     0
```

You might want to remove three rows containing `100` in columns `Red`, `Yellow` and `Green`.